# ListBox selected item refer to a variable

Tags: c#, listbox

Here what I've done.

I made my own class.

```
public class Node
{
    public string name;
    public string type;
    public string vm_name;
    public string vm_ip;
    public string vm_hostname;
}

string[] nodes = new string[2];
Node vm1 = new Node();
Node vm2 = new Node();
```

I set Name property:

```
vm1.name = "name1";
vm2.name = "name2";
```

I put all variables from this type in a string

```
nodes[0] = vm1.name;
nodes[1] = vm2.name;
```

After that I added that array into the listbox items

```
nodeList.Items.AddRange(nodes);
```

Is there a way to access the variable by selecting the item from the list box ?

If there is a better way to do it I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DisplayMember` and `DataSource` properties.And create an array of `Nodes` instead of strings,

```
var nodes = new []
 { 
    new Node { name = "name1" },
    new Node { name = "name2" }
 }

nodeList.DisplayMember = "name";
nodeList.DataSource = nodes;
```

Then you can access your `SelectedItem` and cast it to `Node` like this:

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedNode = nodeList.SelectedItem as Node;

    if (selectedNode != null)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The list is filled with `MyNewApp.Node` instead of the names.

Comment: @MartinNikolaev change your fields to properties. use     `public string name { get; set; }` instead of    ` public string name;`

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? How can I access `var nodes` from other private function... lets say I press a button and I would like the function to operate with that data in `var nodes`

Answer (score -1):

Bind the listbox directly to the Node instance instead of a string.

```
var node = (Node) nodeList.SelectItem;
```

Comment: Right, missed that. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.